# Meaning of "Sanely Insane"?

Tags: meaning

I understand the meaning of being "insanely sane"- whereby one is crazily sane. However, I do not understand the meaning of being "sanely insane"? 
How can one be sanely insane?

Comment: Its obviously a joke. Sort of like "crazy like a fox"...

Comment: Impossible to tell without context. It could be based on the precept that the only sane response to an insane world is insanity.

Comment: "Though this be madness, yet there is method in ’t." (Polonius, "Hamlet" by Shakespeare)

Comment: @christie  You need to add some details on what you have searched so far and/or a reference to where you found the phrase, else you are at risk of having your question closed!

Comment: @RonaldSole - Though this be method, there is madness in 't.  :)

Comment: I believe you are mistaken about what *insanely* means when used in phrases like *insanely cheap*: it simply means extremely or incredibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Hannibal Lector, played by Anthony Hopkins, in the series of movies that began with *The Silence of the Lambs*.

Lector was a brilliant surgeon, a mass murderer, and a master chef who liked to eat his victims, or parts of his victims.

Society considered him "insane", but at the same time, law enforcement officials around the world recognized him as a brilliant man.

Perhaps Lector exemplifies the meaning of "sanely insane".

Aside: In using words like "sane" and "insane", one must keep in mind the perspective according to which such judgments are made. Many societies have judged "insane" what today we consider "sane"; by the same token, many societies have judged "sane" what today we consider "insane". In saying this, I am not saying that Lector was sane, but I'm not saying he was insane either. *Sanely insane* works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the  pilots as in the book Catch-22 who try to get themselves certified insane are **sanely insane**?

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22#Concept):

> catch-22, as formulated by Heller, involves the case of John Yossarian, a U.S. Army Air Forces bombardier, who wishes to be grounded from combat flight. This will only happen if he is evaluated by the squadron's flight surgeon and found "unfit to fly". "Unfit" would be any pilot who is willing to fly such dangerous missions, as one would have to be mad to volunteer for possible death. However, to be evaluated, he must request the evaluation, an act that is considered sufficient proof for being declared sane. These conditions make it impossible to be declared "unfit".